# How to declare nested object types safely in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to create an object what contain groups and the groups have files. The selectable files has an interface, and I want to get error if a group dont contain its files.

```
export interface Group_A_Files {
    'movie': string
    'image': string
    'other': string
}

export interface Group_B_Files {
    'image': string
}

export const groups = {
    'groupA'  : {
        'someField': 'some value',
        'files': <Group_A_Files> {
            'movie': '',
            'image': '',
        } // I want to get an error from the IDE, because other is required in Group_A_Files, but not set by me
    },
    'groupB'  : {
        'someField': 'some value',
        'files': <Group_B_Files>{
            'image': '',
            'bla':  ''
        } // I want to get an error from the IDE, because bla is not defined in Group_B_Files 
    }
}
```

I commented, where I should to get error message from the IDE, but I dont get. What is the right way for this?

I have a lot of groups, and 5 type of group file. These are constants, and hard coded into the app,

I dont want to define the hole groups in interface and then declare it too, just for get the error messages from the IDE, I would like to define the type when I set it.

Here is a [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20Group_A_Files%20%7B%0D%0A%09'movie'%3A%20string%0D%0A%09'image'%3A%20string%0D%0A%09'other'%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Group_B_Files%20%7B%0D%0A%09'image'%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20groups%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09'groupA'%20%20%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09'someField'%3A%20'some%20value'%2C%0D%0A%09%09'files'%3A%20%3CGroup_A_Files%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09'movie'%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09'image'%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%0D%0A%09'groupB'%20%20%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09'someField'%3A%20'some%20value'%2C%0D%0A%09%09'files'%3A%20%3CGroup_B_Files%3E%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09'image'%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%09%09%09'bla'%3A%20%20''%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently typecast, instead you want to assert types, which can be done with a small helper:

```
  function <T> assert(el: T) { return el; }
```

Usable as:

```
'groupB'  : {
    'someField': 'some value',
    'files': assert<Group_B_Files>({
        'image': '',
        'bla':  ''
    }),
}
```

Otherwise you could type the whole object:

```
interface IGroups {
  groupA: {
    someField: string;
    files: Group_A_Files;
 }
};

export const groups: IGroups = {
    'groupA'  : {
        'someField': 'some value',
        'files': <Group_A_Files> {
            'movie': '',
            'image': '',
         }
    },
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It dose the job, and simple enough!